# Why does jupyter choose this environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, conda

I am starting jupyter from conda which is installed in my home directory on MacOS. I opened up a notebook to test a module I installed in conda. To my surprise, this did not work. The module is correctly installed and importing it in interactive python started from conda works. Even stranger is that

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

run in a notebook cell points to a virtual environment completely unrelated to all of this. It is locate in a different subdirectory of the parent directory the test notebook is in. I have started conda in the VS Code interactive shell, maybe this helps.

`which jupyter` correctly points to the conda installation in my home directory, as do `which python`, `which python3` and `which python9` and `which pip3`.

How to I change this weird behavior and what causes it? That is, how can I use the conda python environment instead of this virtual environment?

## Edit

<s>This is somehow related to the port forwarding set up by VS Code. I cannot connect to the server without it.</s> Even connecting via regular ssh and using port mapping via the `-L` flag, this happens.

## Edit 2

I zipped the directory containing the python environment and removed the actual directory. Now the jupyter kernel won't start anymore because of a `FileNotFound` pointing to this exact `python` executable. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a stray Kernel configuration located at `~/Library/Jupyter/kernels`. I faintly remembering installing jupyterlab to the main python installation on this machine once. This must have created this configution. The installation on conda seems to use this configuration. I removed the `~/Library/Jupyter` directory and now everything works as expected.

Note that this configuration hid the correct "Python 3" Kernel. That is, when I tried to create a new python 3 notebook, the menu only listed one "Python 3" entry which referred to the incorrect python 3 installation in the virtual environment.

Comment: Manual kernel registration via `python -m ipykernel install --user ...` will create entries in this location - has nothing to do with where you install Jupyter. If working with Conda, the `nb_conda_kernels` extension is useful for auto-discovery of kernels in Conda environments.